# how to split a list and get the elements out in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
  A      B
[2,3]   [A]
[3,5,7] [O]
[2,1]   [B]
```

I am hoping to break the list A, B by no longer make it a list. The return should look like this

```
A  B
2  A
3  A
3  o
4  o
7  o
2  B
```

my current code is

```
df = df.explode('A')
```

however this explode package seems not working.
I also used `str. split` to remove [] and '', however, that doesn't seem like an efficient way.

Is there any easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Explode works if only your underlying data is list, not string. In you case, you're correct that you use `str.split` to convert your strings into lists (and remove `,` at the same time), then you can use `.explode`:

```
df.assign(A=df['A'].str[1:-1].str.split(',')).explode('A')
```

Output:

```
   A    B
0  2  [A]
0  3  [A]
1  3  [O]
1  5  [O]
1  7  [O]
2  2  [B]
2  1  [B]
```